# Como executar JavaScript externo linkado

Tags: javascript

Possuo o *JavaScript* de data:

```js
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var timeValue = "" + (hours)
timeValue += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes + "h "
timerRunning = true;

mydate = new Date();
myday = mydate.getDay();
mymonth = mydate.getMonth();
myweekday= mydate.getDate();
weekday= myweekday;
myyear= mydate.getFullYear();
year = myyear

if(myday == 0)
day = " domingo, "

else if(myday == 1)
day = " segunda-feira, "

else if(myday == 2)
day = " terça-feira, "

else if(myday == 3)
day = " quarta-feira, "

else if(myday == 4)
day = " quinta-feira, "

else if(myday == 5)
day = " sexta-feira, "

else if(myday == 6)
day = " sábado, "

if(mymonth == 0)
month = " de janeiro de "

else if(mymonth ==1)
month = " de fevereiro de "

else if(mymonth ==2)
month = " de março de "

else if(mymonth ==3)
month = " de abril de "

else if(mymonth ==4)
month = " de maio de "

else if(mymonth ==5)
month = " de junho de "

else if(mymonth ==6)
month = " de julho de "

else if(mymonth ==7)
month = " de agosto de "

else if(mymonth ==8)
month = " de setembro de "

else if(mymonth ==9)
month = " de outubro de "

else if(mymonth ==10)
month = " de novembro de "

else if(mymonth ==11)
month = " de dezembro de "

document.write( day + myweekday + month + year);
```

Como posso linka-lo como um arquivo .js e "chamar" o resultado do *script* dentro de uma DIV, por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Criar um arquivo .js, por exemplo `data.js`;

Dentro do arquivo, crie uma `function` que retorne o que você quer;

Ela deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
function dataExtenso() {
/// Todo o seu processamento
//Agora basta trocar seu document.write( day + myweekday + month + year); por isso
return day + myweekday + month + year;
}
```

### Importe o arquivo no header da página html em que você deseja utilizar este resultado

```
<script src='caminho/para/seu/script/data.js'></script>
```

Em seu div, basta chamar o função. Ai depende de como você queira. Supondo que fez como eu sugeri, ficaria mais ou menos assim:
    
    ...

```
</div>
...
</body>
<script>
  document.getElementById("dataExtenso").innerHTML = dataExtenso();
</script>
```

Isso é igual Neston, existem 1000 maneiras de se fazer. :)